# Vue 3 composition API pass array props through many children

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I need to pass an array from component A (App.vue) through component B to component C. What I do is this (this first step works, just read it to understand):

```
// A.vue
<script setup>
import B from "./B.vue";
import { reactive } from "vue";
let arrayData = reactive({ [ "hello", "no" ] })
</script>
<template>
  <B :arr="arrayData" />
</template>

// B.vue
<script setup>
import C from "./C.vue";
const props = defineProps({
  arr: {
    type: Array
  }
})
</script>
<template>
  {{ props.arr[0] }} //works fine, I get "hello"
</template>
```

But if I do the same thing with the other 2, meaning, I state in B.vue `<C :arr="props.arr" />` instead of `{{ props.arr[0] }}` and I put the same exact props code in C.vue (i.e. const props....) and in C template I call `{{ props.arr[0] }}`, the problem is I get error message.

[image]

Now, my code is not exactly like this, I only changed some names to make it more clear and basic to understand, but that's that. "Reading '0'" is right, since I try to read props.arr[0], but the fact is the error line 33:42 is exactly, in fact, where I try to read that 0 position in the array. It doesn't work only as a prop. If I state an array in C.vue, it works, but as I said I need to pass the array as a prop from A to C. I don't know if I can post a link to the repository on gitHub, but in case I can link it in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation the best solution is to use [`provide/inject`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#provide) to pass data from grandparent component to grandchild one :

```html
// A.vue
<script setup>
import B from "./B.vue";
import { reactive,provide } from "vue";
let arrayData = reactive({ [ "hello", "no" ] })
provide('arr',arrayData):
</script>
<template>
  <B />
</template>
```

in component `C` :

```html
// C.vue
<script setup>

import { inject } from "vue";

const arr = inject('arr'):
</script
```

Comment: This seems to work! I have a related question, is there a way to provide multiple parameters into 1 provide() ? Or do I have just to state a single provide for any parameter I want to pass?

Comment: You could do that by passing an object that holds those parameters like `provide('arrays',{arr1,arr2})`

Comment: Ok I tried and it works, only I had to use [arr1,arr2] and not {arr1,arr2}, the syntax seemed to be wrong, still, it works like this! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @grimoiredark The syntax is not wrong as long as your understanding of it is correct. {arr1,arr2} is an object with arr1 key. [arr1,arr2] is an array of two elements. It makes more for multiple values to have meaningful names, i.e. be an object

Answer (score 0):

In component B.vue you should pass props `:arr="arr"` not `:arr="props.arr"`

```
<script setup>
import C from "./C.vue";
const props = defineProps({
  arr: {
    type: Array
  }
})
</script>
<template>
  <C :arr="arr" />
</template>
```

Comment: I'll have to try this sooner or later, I already solved my issue with provide/inject, but still I ask myself: what's the logic in stating `arr` and not `props.arr`? I mean, the argument you pass through a `:prop` attribute should make sense. for example, if props.arr is an array containing `["hello", "bye"]` and I want to use it directly in B.vue, I have to state like: `let variable = props.arr[0]`, not like: `let variable = arr[0]`...